# How can I combine arrays in one multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have three arrays Like the following:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => option1
    [1] => option2
    [2] => option3
)

Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
    [2] => value3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 43
    [2] => 12
)
```

I want to Combine these arrays like following:

```
Array(

        [0] =>Array(
                    [0] => option1
                    [1] => value1
                    [2] => 15
        )

        [1] =>Array(
                    [0] => option2
                    [1] => value2
                    [2] => 43
        )

        [2] =>Array(
                    [0] => option3
                    [1] => value3
                    [2] => 12
        )
)
```

Comment: a.append(b) -> a[]=b

Comment: `<?php
$final_array = array();
foreach ($first_array as $key=>$val){
 $final_array[] = array($val,$second_array[$key],$third_array[$key]);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always like this behavior of `array_map()` function because it helps me a lot :).See **Example #4 Creating an array of arrays** at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map .I hope this fits your requirement perfectly. :)

```
$array = array('option1','option2','option3');
$array2 = array('value1','value2','value3');
$array3 = array(15,40,12);

$result = array_map(null,$array,$array2,$array3); //see magic here 
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```